# Apache Airflow: run all parallel tasks in single DAG run

Tags: parallel-processing, task, scheduled-tasks, airflow

I have a DAG that has 30 (or more) dynamically created parallel tasks.

I have `concurrency` option set on that DAG so that I only have single DAG Run running, when catching up the history.
When I run it on my server only 16 tasks actually run in parallel, while the rest 14 just wait being queued.

**Which setting should I alter so that I have only 1 DAG Run running, but with all 30+ tasks running in parallel?**

According to [this FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html), it seems like it's one of the `dag_concurrency` or `max_active_runs_per_dag`, but the former seem to be overdriven by `concurrency` setting already, while the latter seemed to have no effect (or I effectively messed up my setup).
Here's the sample code:

```py
import datetime as dt
import logging

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

import config

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'concurrency': 1,
    'retries': 0,
}


def print_operators(ds, **kwargs):
    logging.info(f"Task {kwargs.get('task_instance_key_str', 'unknown_task_instance')}")


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_parallelism_dag',
    start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=True,
    template_searchpath=[config.DAGS_PATH],
    params={'schema': config.SCHEMA_DB},
    max_active_runs=1,
)

print_operators = [PythonOperator(
    task_id=f'test_parallelism_dag.print_operator_{i}',
    python_callable=print_operators,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
) for i in range(60)]

dummy_operator_start = DummyOperator(
    task_id=f'test_parallelism_dag.dummy_operator_start',
)

dummy_operator_end = DummyOperator(
    task_id=f'test_parallelism_dag.dummy_operator_end',
)

dummy_operator_start >> print_operators >> dummy_operator_end
```

**EDIT 1**:
My current `airflow.cfg` contains:

```
executor = SequentialExecutor
parallelism = 32
dag_concurrency = 24
max_active_runs_per_dag = 26
```

My env variables are as following (set all of them different to easily spot which one helps):

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_CONCURRENCY=18
AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG=20
AIRFLOW__CORE__WORKER_CONCURRENCY=22
```

And with that I have following Gantt diagram:
[image]

Which kind of gives me a hint that setting DAG_CONCURRENCY env variable works.

Comment: Are those concurrent tasks of type SubDagOperator?

Comment: @RyanTheCoder no, they are just simple tasks, PythonOperator ones.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to pass a variable to for condition? I mean is it possible to pass a xcom or variable.get instead of range(60)? I am asking this because I want that my limit cames from previous task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual parameter to change was `dag_concurrency` in airflow.cfg or override it with `AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_CONCURRENCY` env variable.

As [per docs I referred to in my question](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html):

> `concurrency`: The Airflow scheduler will run no more than `$concurrency`
>   task instances for your DAG at any given time. Concurrency is defined
>   in your Airflow DAG. If you do not set the concurrency on your DAG,
>   the scheduler will use the default value from the `dag_concurrency`
>   entry in your airflow.cfg.

Which means following simplified code:

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'concurrency': 1,
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_parallelism_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
)
```

should be rewritten to:

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_parallelism_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    concurrency=30
)
```

My code actually has wrong assumption that `default_args` at some point substitute actual kwargs to DAG constructor. I don't know what lead me to that conclusion back then, but I guess setting `concurrency` to `1` there is some draft leftover, which never actually affected anything and actual DAG concurrency was set from config default, which is 16.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `concurrency` config as well in your `airflow.cfg` file. If it is 16, increase it to 32.

If you are using Celery Executor, change `worker_concurrency` to 32.

Comment: I updated my question. I use SequentialExecutor and parallelism's default was 32, so that parameter is out of equation.

Comment: It is weird that you were able to run tasks in parallel with `SequentialExecutor`. We designed `SequentialExecutor` to run tasks serially. If you want to run tasks in parallel use `LocalExecutor`

Comment: Right you are. We have default config value which is overriden by env setting, which I overlooked. Thank you for pointing this out. It is indeed `LocalExecutor`.